# Displaying GoogleDocs on my own domain

Tags: google, embed

Is there a way to have pages from a domain I own mirror my googledocs documents? I know that I could set my domain to redirect to a googledoc URL, but basically I want my visitors to see my googledoc, but still have the URL be my domain, rather than the long googledoc URL. (And I want the documents to remain editable, so it's not just an issue of saving the document as a static file and then uploading to the domain.)

I tried embedding the googledoc in a page on my domain -- but that looked really ugly, and created a situation where there were 2 sets of scroll bars, and wasn't ideal. Maybe there is a way to get around this. I just want my domain to display googledoc pages exactly as they appear when you manually enter the googledoc URL.